# min-heap with custom data type Python?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, data-structures

I want to implement Fast Marching Method for Inpainting in Python. In literature, this has been implemented using a min-heap. Since it involves adding, removing and reordering the data structure many times, and each time extracting the smallest element. So the complexity for these operations need to be min preferably.

I know there is a `heapq` in-built module in Python. It accepts a single `float` value. However, I need to store 3 different information content corresponding to a pixel. Is there a way I can tweak `heapq` to accept a list perhaps?

Alternatively, is there a different data structure with this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`heapq` takes *any* type, as long as they are orderable. The items must either support the `<` lower then or the `<=` lower or equal than operator (`heapq` will use the latter if the first isn't available).

For example, you could use tuples (`(priority, your_data_structure)`); tuples have a relative order based on their contents, starting with the first item.

Or you can use custom objects that implement at least one of `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__` or `__ge__` to implement comparisons between them and thus define an ordering (and, preferably, include a `__eq__` equality method too). The [`functools. total_ordering()` decorator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) would then supply your class with the remaining methods:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class PixelInfo(object):
    def __init__(self, r, g, b):
        self.r, self.g, self.b = r, g, b

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented
        return all(getattr(self, c) == getattr(other, c) for c in 'rgb')

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, type(self)): return NotImplemented
        return self.r + self.g + self.b < other.r + other.g + other.b
```

would be an orderable custom class, which `heapq` would be happy to handle for you.

Comment: Thanks Martijin! That does help a lot! Regarding the rich comparison methods, does the method get called when I use the operator instead of explicitly `x.__lt__(y)`, where `x` and `y` are instances? I tried it. Say `x` is my instance. And when I pass `y` as an `int` or some other data type, I get `NotImplemented` only when I explicitly call the method: `x.__lt__(1)`. If instead, I say `x<1`, I get `True` or `False`. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Yes, that's what the hooks are for; for your custom class to hook into the standard operators. When `x.__lt__(y)` returns `NotImlemented`, Python will use the inverse `y.__ge__(x)` as well, and *it* can still return `True` or `False`.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite follow you here. What if I am passing `y` as an `int`? In this case it does not have an `y.__ge__(x)`. Also, isn't a `True` or `False` an incorrect solution? Since, `other` and `self` are not of the same type.

Comment: Python 2 will order anything by default as well so even if `y` doesn't handle `__ge__` it'll still work with a default ordering. True and False are perfect.